# tools:overrridelibrary ="com.google.andriod.gms.play_services" to force usage

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, android-manifest

I am migrating GCM to FCM. I keep on getting this "suggestion: tools:overrridelibrary". Afetr I add for one com.google.andriod.gms.play_services , I again get for something else. My list is as follows. Is there a way to overcome this?

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="9"
android:targetSdkVersion="17"
tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.all, com.google.android.gms.play_services, com.google.android.gms.ads.impl, com.google.android.gms.ads,
com.google.android.gms.analytics,com.google.android.gms.appinvite,com.google.android.gms.auth.api,com.google.android.gms.auth,
com.google.android.gms.cast.framework,com.google.android.gms.cast,com.google.android.gms.clearcut, com.google.firebase.remoteconfig,
com.google.android.gms.contextmanager,com.google.firebase.crash,com.google.firebase.auth.api,com.google.firebase.database,com.google.firebase.database.connection,
com.google.firebase.storage,com.google.android.gms.all,
com.google.android.gms.ads,
com.google.android.gms.auth,
com.google.android.gms.base,
com.google.android.gms.measurement,
com.google.android.gms,
com.google.android.gms.analytics,
com.google.android.gms.appindexing,
com.google.android.gms.appinvite,
com.google.android.gms.appstate,
com.google.android.gms.cast,
com.google.android.gms.drive,
com.google.android.gms.fitness,
com.google.android.gms.location,
com.google.android.gms.maps,
com.google.android.gms.games,
com.google.android.gms.gcm,
com.google.android.gms.identity,
com.google.android.gms.nearby,
com.google.android.gms.panorama,
com.google.android.gms.plus,
com.google.android.gms.safetynet,
com.google.android.gms.wallet,
com.google.android.gms.wearable,com.google.android.gms.gass,com.google.android.gms.iid
" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make target version 23 apply this on dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
```

Use this on the last line in `build.gradle` outside of dependency:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' in module app gradle

Comment: Thanks. I am over that error now. But getting other kind of error like cannot resolve symbol 'R', FragmentManager,FragmentActivity which I guess might be because of my compile.

Comment: It works. Changed the android {
    compileSdkVersion 23]